Childview not showing when clicking on row for first time
I am writing a SwiftUI application where I click on a row in a list of items to edit an item.  When the application first starts and I click on a row, the item corresponding to the row is not assigned even though I do so in onTap eventf. If I click on another row and then click back to the first row, the application works fine.  I am including a simplified version of the code which replicates the same problem.
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
let items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
@State private var isShowingItem = false
@State private var selectedItem: String?

var body: some View {
    List(items, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item)
            .onTapGesture {
                selectedItem = item
                isShowingItem = true
                print("Selected \(item)")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingItem) {
                if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
                    Text(selectedItem)
                } else {
                    Text("Select again")
                }
            }
    }
}

}

This is SwiftUI. You should add that tag to your question.

Also you need to wrap all of your code in triple-backtick code markers, or indent it.

Try this more robust approach using a dedicated struct Item: Identifiable to store your strings.
This is required for the ForEach to loop over unique Identifiable elements. Using List(items, id: \.self) is bad practice that can lead to problems.
Also move the .sheet outside the List.
See also Sheet docs, it explains that sheet(item: ...) is the appropriate sheet to use when the given item is a data source for the sheet’s content.
struct Item: Identifiable, Hashable {  // <--- here
    let id = UUID()
    var value: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let items = [Item(value: "Item 1"), Item(value: "Item 2"), Item(value: "Item 3")] // <--- here
    
    @State private var selectedItem: Item? // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in  // <--- here
            Text(item.value)
                .id(item)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedItem = item
                    print("Selected \(item)")
                }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in   // <--- here
            Text(item.value)
        }
    }
}


did my answer not worked for you?
